# How do I run a query in MS Access that will only pull records that include a date within the next week (7 days)?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to run a query that will display a table of events coming up in the next 7 days. What criteria should I include to make this happen? Please help.[image]

Comment: Maybe `EventDate BETWEEN Date() AND Date() + 7 `

Answer (score 0):

This should do it
>Date() And <=Date()+7

Comment: Kind of like what @June7 said .. without the code tags and syntax error

Comment: Yes, both are two methods commonly used in ms access for data types like dates.